# How is Win32_DefragAnalysis FilePercentFragmentation Calculated

Tags: powershell, wmi, scom, fragmentation

SCOM 2007 R2 added a fragmentation analsysis health check that is producing warnings on many of my servers. To try to understand how SCOM is determines the fragmentation level, I created the following Powershell script that reproduces the same data:

```
$vols = Get-WmiObject -computername "Z002" Win32_Volume -filter "DriveType=3"
$defragInfo = $vols | %{$_.DefragAnalysis() | add-member -membertype noteproperty vname $_.name -passThru}
$defragInfo | %{$_.DefragAnalysis | add-member -membertype noteproperty DefragRecommended $_.DefragRecommended -passThru | add-member -membertype noteproperty vname $_.vname -passThru} | out-file ./tmp.txt
```

Sample output below. SCOM uses the FilePercentFragmentation number to warn on anything over 10%, what I'm wondering is how is the percentage calculated since it certainly isn't fragmented files divided by total files.

> DefragRecommended             : True
>
> vname                         : I:\
>
> AverageFileSize               :
>   20277223990
>
> AverageFragmentsPerFile       : 1.11
>
> ClusterSize                   : 4096
>
> ExcessFolderFragments         : 0
>
> **FilePercentFragmentation      : 54**
>
> FragmentedFolders             : 1
>
> FreeSpace                     :
>   131237363712
>
> FreeSpacePercent              : 24
>
> FreeSpacePercentFragmentation : 0
>
> MFTPercentInUse               : 10
>
> MFTRecordCount                : 65
>
> PageFileSize                  : 0
>
> TotalExcessFragments          : 4
>
> **TotalFiles                    : 35**
>
> TotalFolders                  : 14
>
> **TotalFragmentedFiles          : 2**
>
> TotalMFTFragments             : 2
>
> TotalMFTSize                  : 606208
>
> TotalPageFileFragments        : 0
>
> TotalPercentFragmentation     : 27
>
> UsedSpace                     :
>   405626204160
>
> VolumeName                    :
>
> VolumeSize                    :
>   53686356787

Comment: By the way, I like your Powershell script. I'm going to pinch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making an educated guess here, but I think it has to do with average **fragmented** file size (e.g. how many files are fragmented vs not), and *their* size as a percentage of total files.

For example, on one of my production servers, I have 0% fragmentation for all files bar one, which happens to be the database MDF file. The 60GB file is in two fragments, but the total fragmentation report states 73%.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think that's a good guess and a likely explaination -- thanks